# Finding the list of common objects between two lists

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of objects of a class for example:

```
class MyClass
{  
   string id,
   string name,
   string lastname
}
```

so for example: `List<MyClass> myClassList;`

and also I have list of string of some ids, so for example:

```
List<string> myIdList;
```

Now I am looking for a way to have a method that accept these two as paramets and returns me a `List<MyClass>` of the objects that their `id` is the same as what we have in `myIdList`.

NOTE: Always the bigger list is `myClassList` and always `myIdList` is a smaller subset of that.
How can we find this intersection?

Comment: As a minor note: the *ideal* option here is to already have the data indexed in a `Dictionary<string, MyClass>`. Is there any chance such a thing exists? It isn't worth the overhead of *creating* an index if it doesn't already exist, but it if does: it could be used

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So you're looking to find all the elements in `myClassList` *where* `myIdList` *contains* the ID? That suggests:

```
var query = myClassList.Where(c => myIdList.Contains(c.id));
```

Note that if you could use a `HashSet<string>` instead of a `List<string>`, each `Contains` test will potentially be more efficient - certainly if your list of IDs grows large. (If the list of IDs is tiny, there may well be very little difference at all.)

It's important to consider the difference between a join and the above approach in the face of duplicate elements in either `myClassList` or `myIdList`. A join will yield every matching pair - the above will yield either 0 or 1 element per item in `myClassList`.

Which of those you want is up to you.

EDIT: If you're talking to a database, it would be best if you didn't use a `List<T>` for the entities in the first place - unless you need them for something else, it would be *much* more sensible to do the query in the database than fetching all the data and then performing the query locally.

Comment: A join is the natural way to do it; you get the performance benefit of your approach with a HashSet, without needing myIdList to be a Hashset

Comment: @ThomasLevesque I disagree there - a join has different semantics (re duplicates). A "contains" maps much more naturally to the specification here, IMO.

Comment: thanks Sir, so I have a EF object that returns me a list of let's say all the teachers in the database, and then I have a list of some of the ID s of some of those teachers and I want to have a list of teachers object but not all of them, the ones that their ID is in that ID list.

Comment: @DevWannaBe: Okay, so what difficulty are you having in translating the code in my answer (or any other answer) into your application? Note that it would be better to do the query *in the database* rather than pulling the *whole* set of teachers first.

Comment: @JonSkeet oh nothing, I was just clarifying more the question I had asked with another example.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet, I was thinking for performance maybe this helps to cache them in memory and have less calls to DB, so you suggest actually a DB query is faster in this case?

Comment: @DevWannaBe: Well it all depends on the details - if you've got a pretty small data set, then caching it all in memory *might* make sense - but if you're asking for (say) 10 elements out of 10 million, then you don't want to fetch all 10 million of them, only to throw most of them away.

Answer (score 5):

That isn't strictly an intersection (unless the ids are unique), but you can simply use `Contains`, i.e.

```
var sublist = myClassList.Where(x => myIdList.Contains(x.id));
```

You will, however, get significantly better performance if you create a `HashSet<T>` first:

```
var hash = new HashSet<string>(myIdList);
var sublist = myClassList.Where(x => hash.Contains(x.id));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a join between the two lists:

```
return myClassList.Join(
        myIdList,
        item => item.Id,
        id => id,
        (item, id) => item)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Does this create a hashlist under the hood? Just curious as to how it compares to the other options given in terms of performance...

Comment: @Chris, I don't know the exact implementation, but yes, I believe it uses a HashSet (or something similar) at some point. You can view the implementation here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#c483e0663f3b76e5

Answer (score 2):

It is kind of intersection between two list so read it like i want something from one list  that is present in second list. Here ToList() part executing the query simultaneouly.

```
var lst = myClassList.Where(x => myIdList.Contains(x.id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use below mentioned code

```
var samedata=myClassList.where(p=>p.myIdList.Any(q=>q==p.id))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myClassList.Where(x => myIdList.Contains(x.id));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
List<MyClass> GetMatchingObjects(List<MyClass> classList, List<string> idList)
{
  return classList.Where(myClass => idList.Any(x => myClass.id == x)).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var q = myClassList.Where(x => myIdList.Contains(x.id));
```